# Processor property/attributes not reachable

Tags: attributes, apache-nifi

In nifi I have a simple flow,

**`GenerateFile -> ConvertCharacterSet -> UpdateAttribute -> PutSFTP`**

in ConvertCharacterSet processor, there're properties
"Input Character Set" , "Output Character Set" ,
both have expression language scope : "Variable registry and Flow file attributes"

When I want to use **"Output Character Set"** value attribute in filename (inside UpdateAttribute processor), it isnt reflected
(placed value).

`filename: converted_to_${"Output Character Set"}_${now():format('yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss', 'CET')}`

Filename I finally get is (eg) : converted_to__2021-02-10_200201

Answer (score 0):

As of this answer, you can't access component properties in NiFi Expression Language. When the "Output Character Set" says it has an expression language scope, it means you can use Expression Language in the value of that property, and the attributes/variables you can use in your expression can come from a Variable Registry and/or the current FlowFile attributes.

You could instead set a FlowFile attribute for which character set to use (let's call it `charset`) then you can set Output Character Set to `${charset}`. You'd also use `charset` in your UpdateAttribute to add it to the filename.

Comment: Thanx. That makes sense. Defined and set charset attribute in GenerateFile and then used it in ConvertCharacter set as value for OutputCharset and then in filename. Works!